# Annotate every other column according with matching condition

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4019    2       CG      2       CC      2       CC      2       CG      2       CC
```

I need to compare the two letters in every other column

If they are match add "`homo`" else add "`het`"

The result of each comparison can be appended to the last column, as in the output bellow.

```
    NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  homo homo homo homo homo  
    NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT  homo homo homo homo homo           
    NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  homo het homo homo homo     
    NC_044998.1     4019    2       CG      2       CC      2       CC      2       CG      2       CC  het homo homo het  homo
```

another example

```
NC_044998.1     3803    0       GG      1       GA      0       GG      1       GA      1       GA      0       GG      0       GG      var     heterozygous    varvar  8       0.727273        3       0.272727
NC_044998.1     3806    0       TT      1       TA      1       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     var     heterozygous    varvar  9       0.818182        2       0.181818
```

output would be

```
NC_044998.1     3803    0       GG      1       GA      0       GG      1       GA      1       GA      0       GG      0       GG      var     heterozygous    varvar  8       0.727273        3       0.272727 homo het homo het het homo homo
NC_044998.1     3806    0       TT      1       TA      1       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     var     heterozygous    varvar  9       0.818182        2       0.181818 homo het het homo homo homo homo
```

have tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=4; length($i)==2 && i<=12; i+=2) substr($i,1,1) == substr($i,2,1); print $0, "homo"}'
```

and

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} { for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=2); for (j=1; j<=2; ++j); $0 = $0 " " (substr($i,j,1) == substr($i,2,1) ? "homo" : "het")} 1'
```

But both will only print "`homo`" in the end of each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP's requirement got more clear now after adding more samples but keeping my first answer here too.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2){
    if(length($i)==2){
      if(substr($i,1,1) == substr($i,2,1)){
        val=(val?val OFS:"")"homo"
      }
      else{
        val=(val?val OFS:"")"het"
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s%s\n",$0,(val!=""?OFS val:""))
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

OR if you don't want to print those lines where NO field is having 2 letter length(basically no value of `homo` or `het`) and you want to skip that line from printing then do following.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2){
    if(length($i)==2){
      if(substr($i,1,1) == substr($i,2,1)){
        val=(val?val OFS:"")"homo"
      }
      else{
        val=(val?val OFS:"")"het"
      }
    }
  }
  if(val!=""){
    print $0,val
  }
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples only. your Input_file doesn't look to me tab delimited in case its tab delimited the add a `BEGIN` section like `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} after` awk  '` line in following solution.

```
awk  '
{
  for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=2){
    if($i==$(i-2)){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")"homo"
    }
    else{
      val=(val?val OFS:"")"het"
    }
  }
  print $0,val
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk  '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=2){                ##Starting a for loop from 6th field to last field which will go every 2nd field from 6th one.
    if($i==$(i-2)){                   ##Checking condition if current field is equals to current-2 field value.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")"homo"      ##if its equal then add homo in val variable here and keep appending value to it.
    }
    else{                             ##else part, in case current field is NOT equal to current-2 field then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")"het"       ##if its NOT equal then add net to val value here.
    }
  }
  print $0,val                        ##Printing current line and val when for loop is completed here.
  val=""                              ##Nullifying val here.
}' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to be working. I'll add a second example of it above.

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, it worked for me for shown samples, could you please do let me know what didn't work here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess another way of explaining this is if a col is same letter 2x, as in AA, print "homo", else print "het", for each other column from start col A to end.col B.

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, sorry but I didn't understand how your first letter is `homo` when 1st line has 4th field as `GG` and 6th field as `GA`, could you please explain more on this one?

Comment: No worries, sorry for not explaining well. The comparison is of substrings within the same field, not across fields. AA = homo, AT = het. Thxs!

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, ok I got it, could you please do check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: Excellent comments++

Comment: Excellent comments indeed! Thanks for the help. it seems to work great now.

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, your welcome, happy to help, cheers and happy learning, sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You are fairly close with your attempt. You may use:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
   s = ""
   for (i=4; length($i)==2 && i<=NF; i+=2)
      s = s " " (substr($i,1,1) == substr($i,2,1) ? "homo" : "het")
   $0 = $0 OFS s
} 1' file
```

```
NC_044998.1 4013    0   TT  2   GG  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT   homo homo homo homo homo
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  2   GG  0   TT   homo homo homo homo homo
NC_044998.1 4018    0   TT  0   TA  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT   homo het homo homo homo
NC_044998.1 4019    2   CG  2   CC  2   CC  2   CG  2   CC   het homo homo het homo
NC_044998.1 3803    0   GG  1   GA  0   GG  1   GA  1   GA  0   GG  0   GG  var heterozygous    varvar  8   0.727273    3   0.272727     homo het homo het het homo homo
NC_044998.1 3806    0   TT  1   TA  1   TA  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  var heterozygous    varvar  9   0.818182    2   0.181818     homo het het homo homo homo homo
```

PS: I have combined both of your input files into single file.

Answer (score 2):

Another example to add to the two other very good answers, that depending on whether the field numbering may change, simply loops over the fields looking for those with a length of `2` characters that are both `[[:alpha:]]` characters where the first equals the second character for `"homo"` otherwise if the two `[[:alpha:]]` characters are not equal `"het"` that relies on a *ternary* and string concatenation could be:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if (length($i)==2 && $i~/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
            s = (substr($i,1,1)==substr($i,2,1)) ? s" homo" : s" het"
        print $0 " " s
        s=""
    }
' file
```

The strings of `"homo"` and `"het"` are appended together in `s` and then output at the end of the record. Thereafter `s` is emptied.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{
>     for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
>         if (length($i)==2 && $i~/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
>             s = (substr($i,1,1)==substr($i,2,1)) ? s" homo" : s" het"
>         print $0 " " s
>         s=""
>     }
> ' file
NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT        homo homo homo homo homo
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT        homo homo homo homo homo
NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT        homo het homo homo homo
NC_044998.1     4019    2       CG      2       CC      2       CC      2       CG      2       CC        het homo homo het homo
```

If you did want to limit the beginning field to field-4 and then only check every-other, then as done in the other two answers, you can loop from field-4 with a loop increment of `2`, e.g.

```
awk '{
    for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=2)
        if (length($i)==2 && $i~/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
            s = (substr($i,1,1)==substr($i,2,1)) ? s" homo" : s" het"
        print $0 " " s
        s=""
    }
' file
```

There are a number of ways to put the strings together and whether you use a *ternary* or `if .. else ..` is largely a matter of taste. Look things over an let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: You have an excellent answer as well. As does @anubhava (which I feel kinda bad, I wrote the answer generally, but then when making it specific to the 4th and every other -- there wasn't a whole lot of difference between the answers....) There are only so many ways to go I guess `:)`

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful for anyone trying to learn awk like myself!

Comment: `awk` is the Swiss-Army knife of text processing. Reference material [StackOverflow AWK tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) and my favorite [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Comment: It indeed is! I think genomics doesn't need more than awk, in a way!